# When downloading a txt-file with send_file, safari and chrome browsers are not able to parse it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, txt, sendfile

I have a set of `entries` which descriptions contain several sentences each. I need to export all of these sentences to a `txt-file. Each sentence gets a unique id and starts on a new line.

```
0000000001[tab] This is line one
0000000002[tab] This is line two
```

I created a `class method` in the `Entry model`, for creating a text file based on the above-mentioned content. This file is being stored and I'm able to open it.

I also created a `controller-action` for downloading the file. This action first creates a `temporary directory` with a `block`, in which the `class method` is being called (accompanied by the `directory`) and next the file is being send to the browser.

The logs show that the file is delivered successfully, but `Chrome` and `Safari` give a `parsing error`.

*entry_model.rb*

```
  def self.download_strings_as_script(dir)
    # Preparing an empty array
    a = []
    # Seeding the array with sentences from all entries which have original content
    Entry.with_original_content.each do |e|
      m = e.original_content.scan(/[^.?!]*[^.?!]*[.?!]/)
      m.each do |me|
        a << me
      end
    end
    # Filtering out some known unnesecary characters and patterns
    a = a.map {|am| am.gsub(/(---)/, "")}
    a = a.map {|am| am.gsub(/^\s+/, "")}
    # Creating the textfile with the array
    File.open("#{dir}/custom_voice_script.txt", 'w+') do |f|
      a.each_with_index do |ae,id|
          # giving the proper format per string, including an id to be used during recording
          f.puts ("%010d" % id) + "[tab] " + ae
      end
    end
```

*entry_controller.rb*

```
  def download_script
    #Create a temporary directory for writing the textfile to
    Dir.mktmpdir do |dir|
      Entry.download_strings_as_script(dir)
      # Waiting 10 seconds
      sleep(10.seconds)
      # Downloading the textfile
      send_file(
        "#{dir}/custom_voice_script.txt",
        filename: "custom_voice_script.txt",
        type: "text/plain"
      )
    end
  end
```

*routes.rb*

```
get 'download_script' => 'entries#download_script'
```

*view*

```
<%= link_to 'Download Voice Script', admin_download_script_path, :format => 'text/plain' %>
```

I'm probably just being stupid, but can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

## Update

Here are the browser errors:
Chrome is giving me a `Failed - Network error`. And with `inspect`:

```
turbolinks.js:154 GET http://127.0.0.1:3000/nl/admin/download_script net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING 200 (OK)
r.send  @   turbolinks.js:154
r.issueRequest  @   turbolinks.js:790
r.visitStarted  @   turbolinks.js:273
r.start @   turbolinks.js:776
r.startVisit    @   turbolinks.js:1002
r.startVisitToLocationWithAction    @   turbolinks.js:894
r.visitProposedToLocationWithAction @   turbolinks.js:271
r.visit @   turbolinks.js:891
r.clickBubbled  @   turbolinks.js:953
(anonymous) @   turbolinks.js:872
```

Safari is only giving me: `cannot parse response" (NSURLErrorDomain:-1017)`

Comment: What's the exact error? Is it a backend error or is the browser give you a specific error?

Comment: @DennyMueller I've added the browser errors as an update to the question. I'm getting a Completed 200 OK in the backend.

Answer (score 0):

The error gives you already the right hints where to look at. Turbolinks can't handle such link where `sent_file` or `send_data` is used. You have to use the `data-no-turbolink` option to disable turbolinks.

```rb
<%= link_to 
  'Download Voice Script', 
  admin_download_script_path, 
  format: 'text/plain',
  data: { turbolinks: false }
%>
```

In case you are using rails version lower than 5 the option should be `data: { no_turbolink: true }`.

Comment: Thank you for your effort, Denny. But it seems like the turbolink errors were only a symptom. The `Dir.mktmpdir block` was causing the problem. If I don't immediately remove the temp directory by closing the block, everything works fine.